# How to measure margin in a classification system?

Tags: machine-learning, experiment-design, metric

I am working on the system that collects optical emission spectra and classifies them into several categories. The classification success rate with the samples that are available to me at the moment is 100%. However, I am trying to future proof the system in case if the new requirements for additional materials to be classified are added in the future and for possible slight variations in the materials that fall under already existing categories.

Since the ultimate goal of the system is classification, my understanding is that I have to maximize the separation between the categories. Since my classifier already reports 100% correct classification, I am wondering what metric should I use to keep improving the system?